# Rewriting the difference of two sums using triangle inequality explanation

Tags: calculus

I'm going through a proof at the moment where the following happens

$$
\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  f(\xi_i) \Delta y_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(\eta_i) \Delta y_i \right| \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i)|\Delta y_i
$$

and it is stated that this happens through the triangle inequality. I simply cannot see how this would happen, could someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sum on the left is finite and the indices are the same the two summation signs can be reduced to one:
\begin{align*}
   \left| \sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\Delta y_i -\sum_{i=1}^n f(\eta_i)\Delta y_i\right| &= \left|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(\xi_i)\Delta y_i - f(\eta_i)\Delta y_i)\right|.
\end{align*}

The $\Delta y_i$ can be distributed so the the right hand side is
\begin{align*}
 \left|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i))\Delta y_i\right|.
\end{align*}

Now apply the **triangle inequality** to get
\begin{align*}
   \left|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i))\Delta y_i\right| &\le \sum_{i=1}^n \left|(f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i))\Delta y_i\right|.
\end{align*}

Now for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $|ab|\le|a||b| \ $ (which holds for complex values as well), and assuming $\Delta y_i \ge 0$, $|\Delta y_i| = \Delta y_i$ so that the right hand side is equal to 
\begin{align*}
   \sum_{i=1}^n |f(\xi_i)-f(\eta_i)|\Delta y_i.
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, appears you answered while I was typing. Yes you have it exactly right.

Comment: Thank you for accepting anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears I answered my own question.

$$
\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  f(\xi_i) \Delta y_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(\eta_i) \Delta y_i \right| = \left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  f(\xi_i) \Delta y_i - f(\eta_i) \Delta y_i \right| \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|f(\xi_i)\Delta y_i - f(\eta_i)\Delta y_i| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|(f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i))\Delta y_i| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i)| |\Delta y_i| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i)| \Delta y_i$$

where the final step is due to the fact that in the proof $\Delta y_i$ is the length of an interval and is therefore never negative so the absolute value can be omitted.